# css hover change color in a search icon?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with a search icon, is it possible change the color of a icon with CSS on hover event?

```
<navbar id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="search"><img src="imagens/search-icon-2.png" width="25"  height="25"/></li>
        <li>

    </ul>
```

Like this: (not working)

```
#menu ul li .search:hover{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: Not unless you're using an icon font.

Comment: The only way to do this is reaplacing the icon on hover (you need to set the icon in the background) or changing the background when an icon has transparency. Any of this cases fit yours?

Comment: Also remove the space between `li` and `.search`

Comment: You know it's an image, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<style>
 .search { /* other stuff */ background:url(url to black image); }
 .search:hover { /* other stuff */ background:url(url to blue image on hover); }
</style>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="search"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that way I know is possible I was trying without using images! But thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make two different search icons (one for each colour). And use the default coloured one as a background image for the li. Like this:

```
#menu ul li.search{
    background-image:url("normal_search_icon.png");
}

 #menu ul li.search:hover{
    background-image:url("coloured_search_icon.png");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that way I know is possible I was trying without using images! But thanks :)